# MySql: Duplicate values when "Insert into" with join and where clause

Tags: mysql

I am trying to combine records from `t1` and `t2`, and insert into `t3`.

```
INSERT INTO t3 (f1, f2)
SELECT t1.f1, t2.f2
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.f3 = t2.f4
WHERE t1.baz = 'bat';
```

As you can see, values from `t1.f1` are used to populate `t3.f1`.  A complication arises because `t3.f1` has a uniqueness constraint, but `t1.f1` does not.  To deal with this, I filter the rows of `t1` using `WHERE t1.baz = 'bat'`.

When `t1` is filtered on `t1.baz = bat`, there are no duplicate values in `t1.f1`.  When I run my query however, it fails upon trying to insert duplicate values in `t3.f1`.

Comment: use replace into

Comment: Provide: sample data (CREATE TABLE for all 3 tables, INSERT INTO with some data, 2-3-5 rows per table), desired result for this src data, precise MySQL version.